# compile time/runtime variable name/enum value name information

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++

Is it possible to obtain variable name or enum value name at compile time/runtime? In particular, `namespace::`/`class::`/`struct::`/`union::`-qualified (with adjustable depth, like have *UNIX* patch unility `-p`/`--strip=` option). In *gcc 4.8.1* I can write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

#include <cstdlib>

enum class mnemocode
{
    fwait,
    finit,
    fninit,
    fstsw,
    fnstsw,
    // ...
    sahf,
    ret,
    prologue,
    epilogue,
    sp_inc,
    sp_dec,
    call
};

inline /* till C++14 cannot be constexpr */
auto mnemocode_name(mnemocode _mnemocode)
{
    switch (_mnemocode) {
    case mnemocode::fwait    : return "fwait";
    case mnemocode::finit    : return "finit";
    case mnemocode::fninit   : return "fninit";
    case mnemocode::fstsw    : return "fstsw";
    case mnemocode::fnstsw   : return "fnstsw";
    // ...
    case mnemocode::sahf     : return "sahf";
    case mnemocode::ret      : return "ret";
    case mnemocode::prologue : return "prologue";
    case mnemocode::epilogue : return "epilogue";
    case mnemocode::sp_inc   : return "sp_inc";
    case mnemocode::sp_dec   : return "sp_dec";
    case mnemocode::call     : return "call";
    default : return "[unknown instruction]";
    }
}

inline
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out, mnemocode _mnemocode)
{
    return out << mnemocode_name(_mnemocode);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << mnemocode::fwait << std::endl; // fwait
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But I want to be able to do the following:

```
template< typename M, typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_same< mnemocode, typename std::remove_reference< typename std::remove_cv< M >::type >::type >::value >
inline constexpr
auto mnemocode_name(M && _mnemocode)
{
    constexpr auto const depth = std::numeric_limits< std::size_t >::max(); // remove all qualifiers before last operator ::
    return abi::__get_value_info(_mnemocode).name(depth); // compile time if M is constexpr
}
```

by means of some imaginary `constexpr abi::__get_value_info(symbol)` class.

*GCC* allows me to write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <cstdlib>

template< typename T >
/* cannot be constexpr :( */
const char * this_type()
{
    return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
}

template< typename T >
std::string theirs_type()
{
    int status = 0;
    auto realname_(abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(T).name(), nullptr, nullptr, &status));
    switch (status) {
    case -1: return "Could not allocate memory";
    case -2: return "Invalid name under the C++ ABI mangling rules";
    case -3: return "Invalid argument to demangle";
    }
    std::string os(realname_);
    std::free(realname_);
    if (std::is_volatile< T >::value) {
        os = "volatile " + os;
    }
    if (std::is_const< T >::value) {
        os += " const";
    }
    if (std::is_rvalue_reference< T >::value) {
        os += " &&";
    } else if (std::is_lvalue_reference< T >::value) {
        os += " &";
    }
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << this_type< decltype(static_cast< double const >(double())) >() << std::endl; // const char* this_type() [with T = double]
    std::cout << theirs_type< double const && >() << std::endl; // double &&
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But this is only about the type names and too far from compile time deduction.

I guess that's all I come up here, would require almost embedded into my executable debugger and the availability of the section with the debug information. But I still do not think, that it's impossible at all.

Answer (score 1):

There may be other solutions but the way I normally do this is to play with #defines

1) define your enums in a file (say enumdef.h)

```
ENUMDEF(fwait)
ENUMDEF(finit)
...
ENUMDEF(call)
```

2) Declare a header for the enums

```
#ifndef EnumDefEnum_h
#define EnumDefEnum_h
enum mnemcode
{
#define ENUMDEF(x) x,
#include "enumdef.h"
#undef ENUMDEF
mnemcodeMax
};
#endif
```

3) To print them

```
#include "enumdefenum.h"
static const char* mnem_str[] =
{
#define ENUMDEF(x) #x,
#include "enumdef.h"
#undef ENUMDEF
    ""
};

const char* mnem_name(mnemcode index)
{
    return mnem_str[index];
}
```

4) You could even use them in switch statements if you keep to a naming convention

```
switch (index)
{
// Put in a pragma to tell you which one it is because the compiler will
// tell you the  line number in enumdef.h: not the one in this file
#pragma message("switch statement in some routine")
#define ENUMDEF(x) \
case x: Do##x(whatever); break;
#include "enumdef.h"
#undef ENUMDEF
}
```

Comment: Do you know any alternatives to x macro here? I'm about to use x macro for production and i'm really, really scared i'll have to come back to this. All this macros are evil posts scare me so much!

Comment: I have used this several times in production code - it has never been a problem.  It is a lot easier to maintain.  You don't get lengthy nested switch statements and the compiler tells you what is missing when you add a new enum.  Just try a noddy program to check out the mechanics.  If macros were evil, they wouldn't have put them in the language.

Comment: Yeah I made some semi complex samples and "lab" code to make sure I got them right, at least right enough. And yes, I guess if they're there It's for a reason. Maintaining an enum and a name map for every enumerator is just way shorter and even easier to understand, I commented everything close to the point of overkill... Yet, my guts tell me there's a problem with that design, that that's not the intended use for enums. Should I write a new question?

Comment: The problem isn't with writing the initial code: it is the maintenance.  The question you need to ask is **how much code do I need to modify when I add a new enum** and **how can I make sure I've covered every case**.   The strings are easy to maintain. It is the switch statements and if statements that cause problems.

Comment: That question lead me to realise it's unavoidably hard to add a new enumerator to my program, and adding it's name string to the map is the least of the troubles you have to go through. There's even a template struct which has to be specialised for every enumerator, and so on. Thank you for the tips.